# taking difference of array with specific spacing in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm approximating a first order derivative of an array in numpy using `np.ediff1d`:

```
x=array([ 1,  2,  5, 10])
np.ediff1d(x) # = array([1, 3, 5])
```

`np.ediff1d` uses consecutive elements of the array. Is there a way to control the spacing i.e. is there a numpy function that calculates the difference between every n-th element, as sliding window?

example: `newdiff(x, window=2)` would be: `[5-1, 10-2]` or `[4, 8]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n=2
v = [x[i+n]-x[i] for i in range(len(x)-n)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply take the difference of shifted slices:

```
n = 2
x[n:] - x[:-n]
```